# Explanation regarding "generator object"

Tags: python, for-loop

Could some one please explain why this code:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = ((element) for element in A)
print(B)
```

produces: `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0319B490>`

while this code:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
for element in A:
    print(A)
```

produces:

```
1
2
3
4
```

They seem to be the same to me but they are obviously different. I can't figure out the difference between them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first code is a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), hence it will create a generator object at a certain memory address. If you want to use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) then use `[]` as per:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [element for element in A]
print(B)
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = []
for element in A:
    B.append(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first is not a loop but a generator expresion so will printing B it shows us the object ref.
The second one Is a loop, it iterates over the elements and print them all.

Try doing this, you can iterate over a generator:

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = ((element) for element in A)
for e in B:
    print(e)
```

This will result in the same as your second expresion:

```
for e in A:
    print(e)
```

Notice that you can only iterate once until the generator is exausted.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental difference between the two is that a generator expression defines an object that will generate values as you loop.  In other words, the values will be generated on each iteration and consumed on demand. With a list comprehension, the values are created up-front and will consume as much memory as is required to hold all the values in memory at once.

It's easy to look at these two constructs as being the exact same thing but in the case of the generator, you are consuming the values on demand in a lazy way.  This is very useful because you don't have pay the cost of memory to hold all of the data up-front.